# Azure sql private endpoint ARM template help needed

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-rm-template

```
 {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints",
            "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
            "name": "[variables('privateEndpointName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('sqlServerName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "subnet": {
                    **id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', variables('vnetName')),'/subnets/default')]"')]"**
                },
                "privateLinkServiceConnections": [
                    {
                        "name": "[variables('privateEndpointName')]",
                        "properties": {
                            "privateLinkServiceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers',variables('sqlServerName'))]",
                            "groupIds": [
                                "sqlServer"
                            ]
```

Getting error Resource vnetI not found. vnet is located in different subscription to where template is running.
How to get vnet ID in different subscription using arm template?

Answer (score 0):

default value is the current subscription. Specify subscription and resource group to solve the issue.

```
"[resourceId('11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111', 'otherResourceGroup', 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts','examplestorage')]"
```

[link to MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#resourceid)

Comment: That resource ID is subnet/storage reference. Where is the Private Endpoint Resource group reference in type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints"?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is just wrong reference of parameters. You can reference the other VNet in a different subscription for the parameter `"id"` with its ID generated from `resourceId` function. It returns the unique identifier of a resource. You use this function when the resource name is ambiguous or not provisioned within the same template.

Default value is the current subscription. Specify `subscriptionId`, `resourceGroupName`, `resourceType` and `resourceName` value of the other subscription as you need to retrieve a resource in another subscription.

Changes:

**From:**

```
"id": resourceId([subscriptionId], [resourceGroupName], resourceType, resourceName1, [resourceName2], ...)
```

**To:**

```
"id": "[resourceId('OthersubscriptionId','virtualNetworkResourceGroup', 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', 'virtualNetworkName', 'subnet1Name')]"
```

this is how it looks...

```
{
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints",
            "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
            "name": "[variables('privateEndpointName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('sqlServerName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "subnet": {
                    "id": "[resourceId('xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx', 'virtualNetworkResourceGroup', 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', 'virtualNetworkName', 'subnet1Name')]"
                },
                "privateLinkServiceConnections": [
                    {
                        "name": "[variables('privateEndpointName')]",
                        "properties": {
                            "privateLinkServiceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers',variables('sqlServerName'))]",
                            "groupIds": [
                                "sqlServer"
                            ]
                           }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
```

Refer: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/create-private-endpoint-template#:%7E:text=%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22apiVersion%22%3A%20%222020-06-01%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22%5Bvariables(%27privateEndpointName%27)%5D%22%2C) and [resourceId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#resourceid)

**Update ---**

**Additional example:** To get the resource ID for a resource in a different subscription and resource group, provide the subscription ID and resource group name.

```
"[resourceId('xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx', 'otherResourceGroup', 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts','examplestorage')]"
```

The following example shows how a resource from an external resource group can easily be used:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "location": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "virtualNetworkResourceGroup": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "subnet1Name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "nicName": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "subnet1Ref": "[resourceId(parameters('virtualNetworkResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('virtualNetworkName'), parameters('subnet1Name'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
      "name": "[parameters('nicName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('subnet1Ref')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**---**

Comment: id": "[concat(resourceId([OthersubscriptionId], [OtherresourceGroupName], 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', OtherVnetName),'/subnets/default')]"')]"  Does it need /ResourceGroups? It is not working

Comment: required since you are running it from a different scope / resource group. What error are you seeing ?

Comment: Getting syntax error "[concat(resourceId([OthersubscriptionId], [OtherresourceGroupName], 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', OtherVnetName),'/subnets/default')]"')]"

Comment: There seem to be an extra bracket, try this -  "[concat(resourceId([OthersubscriptionId], [OtherresourceGroupName], 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', OtherVnetName),'/subnets/default')]"

Comment: Can you post the exact syntax error that you see and the code as is you are using. Note: you need to replace the place holder and just keep the values as string in ' '

Comment: try as updated:  "id": "[resourceId('xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx', 'virtualNetworkResourceGroup', 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', 'virtualNetworkName', 'subnet1Name')]"